# Why does the return statement not return any text, whilst print does?

Tags: python, function, return

when i run

```
profitable_gamble(0.2, 50, 9)
```

with this function there is no output

```
def profitable_gamble(prob, prize, pay):
    if prob * prize > pay:
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
```

however when i change the function to use print()

```
def profitable_gamble(prob, prize, pay):
    if prob * prize > pay:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

I get "true" as expected. how can I get this to happen while using return rather than print?

Comment: Because you never instruct to *print* the output. You can print the output of the old function with `print(profitable_gamble(...))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you *think* your code should do:

```
def profitable_gamble(prob, prize, pay):
    if prob * prize > pay:
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"


returned_value = profitable_gamble(0.2, 50, 9)
print(returned_value)
```

But then you never tell it to print anything, so it doesn't. If you only call this:

```
profitable_gamble(0.2, 50, 9)
```

Then your function returns "true" or "false" nonetheless.... you just never do anything with it, so it just goes to die in the call stack.

EDIT: you may also be confused because of the use of command-line (or something like Ipython notebooks). In those interactive shells, if you do:

```
profitable_gamble(0.2, 50, 9)
>> "true"
```

Then indeed it does show the value on screen. However, this is just because you're using a *shell* which (presumably) outputs the result of the call to the console for you. So essentially that shell (be it a terminal or some interactive notebook) does for you the additional print() statement....

As a note - there is little reason in general to do something like

```
return "true"
```

In python. Generally you would want to just use the boolean:

```
return True
```

(notice the capital T).

Especially since you can anyway do print(some_boolean_variable) or str(some_boolean_variable).... The added benefits being that it's much easier to test a boolean value than to compare the string "true" everytime...

Comment: Thank you (specifically for the edit part) i've been using a site that has challenges and getting them wrong even though i can do the the print way on pycharm and was very confused.

Comment: There's no reason to use `return True` and `return False` with an `if` anyway. The whole method could simply be `return prob * prize > pay`.

Comment: @EricDuminil fully agreed. But I don't think the op had that much experience in my Python, so didn't think it was necessary to add to much detail on too many things...